# Python3: Calling functions saved as values (strings) in a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

*Background:*

I am reading a python file (.py) that has a number of functions defined and using a regex to get the names of all the functions and store them in a list.

```
d_fncs = {}
list_fncs = []

with open('/home/path/somefile.py', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        search = re.search(r'def (.*)\(', row)
        if search:                             
            list_fncs.append(search.group(1))
```

The above works fine and as expected returns a list of of the function names as strings. I have another list which I plan to use as a counter.

```
counter = [str(i) for i in range(1,len(list_fncs)+1)]
```

Finally, I zip the two lists to get a dictionary where the 'keys' are numbers and the associated 'values' are function names

```
d_fncs = dict(zip(counter,list_fncs))
```

*The problem:*

The intent here is to ask user for an input  which would be matched with the key of this dictionary (counter). Once the key is matched, the function associated with it is executed. Something like this happens later in the code:

```
def option_to_run(check, option_enter_by_user):
    if check == 'True':
        return (connection(d_fncs[option]))

def connection(fnc):
    conn_name = Connect(some args..) #class imported 
    fnc(conn_name)
```

In this case, as the values from dict are string, I get the following error:

```
File "/home/path/filename.py", line 114, in connection

    fnc(conn_name)

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

However, if I manually make a dict and run it then I have no issues and functions work as expected:

```
d_fncs_expected = {'1': function1, '2': function2, ....}
```

Right now what I am getting is this:

```
d_fncs = {'1': 'function1', '2': 'function2', ....}
```

....what can I do to get the dictionary to work in a way so I can call these functions? I want the values not to be strings but a type:class

Comment: Why go to all this trouble to reinvent `import`? Just import that file and use `dir()` to get the names of the classes defined in it.

Comment: `dir` won't give you the names in definition order, but are you sure numbering these by definition order is really the best way to go about referring to them? Also, your regex is going to give you wrong results and false positives, such as for methods, nested functions, and comments and string literals that just happen to have a match for `def (.*)\(` in them.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have any method named fnc? If so then  change the name fnc to something else.fnc is a variable you can't call a variable like a method.

Comment: This is all being done in the same file. So basically there are a bunch of functions defined in this file and at the end of the file I am doing all of this ... are you suggesting to do something like this: a=filename.dir()

Comment: You can sort the results of `dir()` by line number.

Comment: If you're doing it all in the same file you can just use `globals()`.

Comment: @kindall - Thanks for the suggestion! I had never used globals() and didn't even know what it does. Read up on it and implemented it and got it to do what I was thinking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
fnc(conn_name)
```

to

```
eval(fnc)(conn_name) # or eval(fnc(conn_name))
```

**or**

```
globals()[fnc](conn_name)
```

**For example**

```
def myfn(arg):
    print(arg +" is printed")
d = {1: 'myfn'}
fun_name = d[1] # 'myfn' 

>>>fun_name("something")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>eval(fun_name)("something")
something is printed
>>>globals()[fun_name]("someting")
something is printed
```